# Jena objectProperty sparql

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

this is a part from my ontology

```
    <rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:diag="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Symptom"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Desease"/>
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#hasSymptom">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Symptom"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Desease"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#DesId">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Desease"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#SympId">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Symptom"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#DesLabel">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Desease"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#SympLabel">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#Symptom"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
<diag:Desease rdf:about="http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#shellfish allergy">
  <diag:hasSymptom>oliguria</diag:hasSymptom>
  <diag:hasSymptom>tonic seizure</diag:hasSymptom>
  <diag:hasSymptom>hair loss</diag:hasSymptom>
  <diag:DesId>DES:000006</diag:DesId>
  <diag:DesLabel>shellfish allergy</diag:DesLabel>
</diag:Desease>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to get the symptoms "oliguria , tonic seizure, hair loss" using the object Property "hasSymptom" query in Jena, 
 and this is my Code:

```
public static ObservableList<String> getMoreSymptoms(String item) {

    String moreSymptomsQuery
            = "PREFIX diag: <http://www.hamzadje28/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#> "
            + "SELECT ?Symp"
            + "WHERE {\""
            + item
            + "\" diag:hasSymptom ?Symp}";



    Query query = QueryFactory.create(moreSymptomsQuery1);
    QueryExecution executeQuery = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, modelDiag);
    org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet res = executeQuery.execSelect();

    modelDiag.read(pathDiag);
    while (res.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution qs = res.nextSolution();
      Resource Symp = qs.getResource("Symp");

        moreSymp.add(Symp.toString());
    }

    return moreSymp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    getMoreSymptoms("diabetes mellitus");

    System.out.println(getMoreSymptoms("diabetes mellitus").size());

    System.out.println(moreSymp);
```

the result is an empty list []; I need some help please....

Comment: You have `+ "SELECT ?Symp"
            + "WHERE {\""` in your query.  That turns into `SELECT ?SympWHERE {`, but you never use a variable `?SympWHERE`, so there are no results. Be careful with space and string concatenation.  Also, `where` is optional, so you might as well do `select ?Symp{ ... }`, which is fine.

Comment: thank you @JoshuaTaylor , but i still have the same problem: no result